# How do additional input output pairs help with a Meet in the Middle attack on Double DES

Tags: des, multiple-encryption, meet-in-the-middle-attack

Double DES is vulnerable to a Meet in the Middle attack where an attacker generates intermediate values and then matches them up to find candidate key pairs. For Double DES using $56$ bit keys and $1$ input/output pair you get $2^{48}$ candidate key pairs. How does this scale when you use multiple input/output pairs?

edit: To be more explicit: How much does each additional input/output pair reduce the number of candidate keys?

Comment: Because there can be more than one candidate solution. having additional pairs helps you to determine the key!

Comment: I understand that. I was asking how much each additional input/output pair reduces the amount of candidate keys.

Comment: Hint: As a first-order approximation, assume that double-DES is, for each fixed key, an independent random permutation of the message space. As a refinement, you may want to consider what being able to choose plaintext, and the DES complementation property, change to that.